# Find total logged in time of users in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to prepare a report in codeigniter  of the login and logout time of users. I have overridden the session library and changed the function of `set_userdata` according to it.

My problem is when user doesn't select the logout button, or if he/she is logged in simultaneously from more then one system; in that case how can I keep a log of login and logout time?

I added the following code to the `session_destroy` function of the session library

```
$session_id=$this->userdata['session_id']; 
$c_array=array('logout_time'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); 
$this->CI->db->where('session_id',$session_id); 
$this->CI->db->update('login_activities',$c_array);
```

but the `session_id` changed after some time in the `ci_session` table

Comment: Can you put some code that you have tried.

Comment: in session lib i use
`$session_id=$this->userdata['session_id'];
                        $c_array=array('logout_time'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                        $this->CI->db->where('session_id',$session_id);
                        $this->CI->db->update('login_activities',$c_array);`

Comment: but the session id changed after some time in ci_sesion table

Comment: `session_id` is changed every 300 seconds, and deleted every 7200 seconds by default; (take a look at [CI doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)). It's better to use `user_id` in `login_activities` to log the users' actions.

Comment: please provide the structure of login_activities table

Comment: @ReNiShAR  `id` ,`session_id` ,`users_id` ,`login_time` ,`logout_time` 
 login time be found but how to get logout time?

Comment: @HashemQolami it is good idea but what if user is login more one systems or browser so i need unique id like session_id.

Comment: @HashemQolami is this better idea if i change in config file variable sess_time_to_update :300 seconds to 1 day?

Comment: you can write a refresh code. Every 5 or 10seconds refresh your header or home page, at that time insert current time as logout_time.            You can write code for save log out time when log out is pressed.But not properly log out that is not worked

Comment: @reena.sharam No, That's a bad practice to increase the update time, for different browsers, check the `user_agent` column. a combination of `user_id` and `user_agent` would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we cant always get the logout time, because if the user close the browser there won't be able to add a logout time, in the case of normal logout its ok..

here my suggession is:

instead of **logout_time** we need **current_time** and a **usage field**

if the user is logged an ajax is run on page for every second or (may be in 3 seconds or 5)

at every time the ajax runs: the current_time updated with the current time stamp, and the usage field must be updated with time in seconds that can be calculated by difference in login_time and current time

use the following function:

```
function getTimeInSec($t1, $t2)
{
    $timeFirst  = strtotime($t1);
    $timeSecond = strtotime($t2);
    $differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;
    return $differenceInSeconds;
}
```

here $t1 is the current_time and $t2 is the login_time....
(both ar in format 'Y-m-d H:i:s')

script for ajax call:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    getRefresh(1000);
});
function getHeader()
{
     $.post("<?php echo site_url('mycontroller/refreshAjax');?>", {
 },
 function(response)
 {
 });
}
function getRefresh(tim)
{
    getHeader();
    setTimeout("getRefresh("+tim+")", tim);
}
</script>
```

in the controller function  refreshAjax() there must be update query for the table to update...